# What do spacelike, timelike and lightlike spacetime interval really mean?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, causality

Suppose we have two events $(x_1,y_1,z_1,t_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2,t_2)$. Then we can define

$$\Delta s^2 = -(c\Delta t)^2 + \Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2 + \Delta z^2,$$

which is called the spacetime interval. The first event occurs at the point with coordinates $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and the second at the point with coordinates $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ which implies that the quantity

$$r^2 = \Delta x^2+\Delta y^2+\Delta z^2$$

is the square of the separation between the points where the events occur. In that case the spacetime interval becomes $\Delta s^2 = r^2 - c^2\Delta t^2$. The first event occurs at time $t_1$ and the second at time $t_2$ so that $c\Delta t$ is the distance light travels on that interval of time.

In that case, $\Delta s^2$ seems to be comparing the distance light travels between the occurrence of the events with their spatial separation. We now have the following definitions:

- If $\Delta s^2 <0$, then $r^2 < c^2\Delta t^2$ and the spatial separation is less than the distance light travels and the interval is called timelike.
- If $\Delta s^2 = 0$, then $r^2 = c^2\Delta t^2$ and the spatial separation is equal to the distance light travels and the interval is called lightlike.
- If $\Delta s^2 >0$, then $r^2 > c^2\Delta t^2$ and the spatial separation is greater than the distance light travels and the interval is called spacelike.

These are just mathematical definitions. What, however, is the physical intuition behind them? What does an interval being timelike, lightlike or spacelike mean?

Answer (score 89):

Let's suppress some dimensions to simplify:

$$\Delta s^2 = -(c\Delta t)^2 + \Delta x^2 $$

This quantity $$\Delta s^2$$ is preserved by changes of reference frame, just as in Galilean physics the quantity $$\Delta r^2 = \Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2 $$ is preserved by rotations.

Notice it is also the equation of a hyperbola. Thus, *the effect of a frame shift is to slide events around on hyperbolae of constant $\Delta s^2$*.

Here's a helpful image from Wikipedia (attribution below):

[image: Minkowski space]

Ignore the vectors and just look at the hyperbolae. Events on a given hyperbola must, under a given frame boost, *remain on that hyperbola*.

Now you might notice those hyperbolae seem to come in two classes, those on the top and those on the bottom. The "v=c" hyperbolae - the straight lines - divide the two. Events on those are said to be "lightlike (or null) separated from the origin". Notice that for these, $\Delta s^2$ is just *zero*.

The hyperbolae in the purple regions are said to be *timelike* separated from the origin. This is because no matter how much they slide around on their hyperbolae, *their ordering compared to the origin never changes*. Any events in the purple regions which occur before (after) the origin will occur before (after) the origin *to all observers*. Thus, this set of events - plus the null events - is said to be *causally connected with the origin*. The fact that the ordering of these events with the origin *in time* is fixed motivates the term.

The hyperbolae in the white regions do not have this property. Some observers think they happened before O, while some think they happened after. It had therefore better be true that nothing about O depend logically on happening after (or before) these events! Otherwise we could break logic by running really fast.

However, notice that it is not possible to slide the white-region events from one side of the origin to the other. This makes the separation more like our normal ideal of "distance", so we say the events are *spacelike separated*.

Image attribution:
["Minkowski lightcone lorentztransform" by Maschen - Own work. Licensed under Public Domain via Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Minkowski_lightcone_lorentztransform.svg#/media/File:Minkowski_lightcone_lorentztransform.svg)

Comment: Can you tell me which book can I follow for studying special relativity in matrix and tensor notation?

Comment: To really grasp it: Our "real" world is taking place only in the timelike-region(s)?

Comment: @Ben Oct  no, ordinary real spacetime where we all live corresponds to the whole of this diagram, not just some regions of it. There are other diagrams, related to black holes, where things are more complicated, but this diagram is showing the ordinary situation in ordinary spacetime. Worldlines of ordinary things such as bricks and bicycles extend from the bottom to the top throughout the diagram.

Answer (score 43):

Spacelike separation means that there exists a reference frame where the two events occur simultaneously, but in different places. Timelike separation means that there exists a reference frame where the two events occur at the same place, but at different times. Lightlike means that, well, light could travel between those points.

Comment: Space-like spacetime sounds to me more like "Instantaneous action at a distance".

Comment: @ Markoul11 Just the opposite. No action. Spacelike separation implies no causal relation between events. (See Mayou36's answer.)

Comment: @D.Halsey, to be precise there is no causal relation b/w the 2 events for the observer for whom the two events occur simultaneously. For a different observer, the 2 events might be causally connected.

Answer (score 36):

Let's put it **very simple**: They tell you "how far something is apart compared to c"

**time-like**: if you are fast enough, you can be at (think spatial, like "at the festival") event a **and** at event b, it is only a "matter of time" until you see the second event

**space-like**: the two events are too far apart (in space). You cannot see both of them together, no matter how fast you are. As soon as event a happened and you go as fast as possible, event b will have happened before you arrive there.

**light-like**: exactly in between, the events are so far away that if you are as fast as light, you can see both events. If they are further away, they become *space-like*, if they are closer they become *time-like*

So a space-like separation makes *any* causal relation between the two events impossible, i.e. one *cannot* cause or influence the other.$^1$

*1) as mentioned, a common cause (an event that is time-like to both events) can still make the two correlated.*

Comment: Space-like separation doesn't make correlation impossible, only causal link between the two events is impossible. They still can have a common cause and thus be correlated.

Comment: @Ruslan I fully agree, thanks for the comment. My brain merged "causal relation" to "correlation". I've changed that and added a comment to explain that further.

Comment: Space-like spacetime sounds to me more like "Instantaneous action at a distance".

Comment: @Markoul11, no, that seems wrong. It's more about the "spacial reachability", more like "you cannot dance at two weddings": Imagine you're here, seeing the light of the sun. Now, two million light years away and in a million years, a star will explode. If you wanna witness this too (not just the sun now), you're to late, even when traveling with speed of light. However, the star will explode in a million years, definitely nothing "instantaneous" about this.

Comment: Why is your straightforward answer not the most upvoted? (Why should one make things complicated that don't have to be?) Beats me. Have my upvote.

Answer (score 16):

Timelike is when an event is inside the lightcone (as you have mentioned) and as a result, one event CAN affect the other event (there can exist a causality between the two events. E.g. lets say there are two events, where I shoot a laser and another event where someone gets hit by a laser. If they are timelike seperated then the laser that hit the dud could have been from me).

Spacelike is when the two events are outside lightcone (as you have also mentioned) and as a result, one event CANNOT affect the other event. (For the previous example, it is impossible that my laser hit the dude and killed him, so I can safely conclude that someone else shot the laser to kill him.)

Lightlike is a special case which is like inbetween the two. For me to kill him, all the interval inside must have been vaccuum.

Comment: This is an excellent and easy way to think about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> spacelike, timelike and lightlike [...] What, however, is the physical intuition behind?

Using "*physical*" terminology means (foremost, and even exclusively) to refer to distinguishable "participants" (a.k.a. "principal identifiable points", or "material points") where

- each is (thought as being) capable, at least in principle, of determining with whom they had been coincident ("meeting at an event"), and with whom not, and in which sequence one had taken part in different concidence events, and
- each is (thought as being) capable, at least in principle, of observing and recognizing others in their distinguishable states (having taken part in particular coincidence events, having collected certain observations), thus exchanging signals between each other (i.e. especially referring to one's first observation of a given signal state).

In this terminology, any one event is characterized by who had taken part, and by which signals (of other events) the participants first observed at this coincidence occasion.

The relation between two distinct given events may accordingly be characterized as follows:

- either all participants in one event had thereby first observed the (signals of) the other event. Such pairs of events are conventionally characterized by a **null interval**,
- or else at least one identifiable participant having taken part in both events (or at least being thought as having taken part in both events). Considering three or more such events they are conventionally assigned suitably generalized metric relations between each other to satisfy the [inverse triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reversal_in_Minkowski_space),
- or neither. Metric relations assigned to three or more such events may or may not satisfy the triangle inequality.

However, as technical terms, the words "*[spacelike, timelike and lightlike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_structure#Tangent_vectors)*" require some (not quite arbitrary) additional assignment of coordinates to a given set of events, in order to describe their relation as elements of a [Lorentzian manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold#Lorentzian_manifold).

Answer (score 0):

Consider an interval from event *a* to event *b*:

- The interval is **time-like** if it large in time but small in space. If you are at event *a*, you have enough time to get to event *b*. Event *a* can directly influence event *b*, and all observers will agree that event *a* happened before event *b*. (Think "the change in time is greater than the change in space.")
- The interval is **space-like** if it is large in space but small in time. If you are at event *a*, there's no way to move quickly enough to get to event *b*. Event *a* cannot directly influence event *b*, and observers may disagree as to which event occurred first. (Think "the change in space is greater than the change in time.")
- The interval is **light-like** if it is as large in space as it is in time (relative to *c*). (Think "the change in time equals the change in space.")

If a light-like interval moves further apart in space or closer in time it becomes space-like; if it moves further apart in time or closer in space it becomes time-like.

(This answer is a rewrite of [Mayou36](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/103653/mayou36)'s.)

Answer (score -8):

In the context of different spacetimes and not spacetime intervals within the same spacetime. The definition could be extended as following:

Simply put, time-like or light-like is our known spacetime where [causality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality) is dictated by the speed of light. Thus for example, light-like in the vacuum where the speed of light is $c$ and time-like inside a transparent medium like glass where the speed of light is lower than $c$.

Space-like is a hypothetical spacetime where causality is dictated by *faster than light FTL* speed limit and when projected in our time-like or light-like spacetime this could even resemble to *"Instantaneous action at a distance" or else known by famous Einstein as "*Spooky action at a distance*".*

However, such a spacetime domain has not yet being discovered within our cosmos and therefore not regarded today as a  possible explanation for the observed [Quantum Entanglement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement) phenomena.

Nevertheless, Dark Energy seems to have a space-like spacetime behavior.

Comment: You are very confused! Space-like, time-like and light-like do not refer to different kinds of spacetime, but rather to different separations of events within a given spacetime.

Comment: @D.Halsey I have the novelty to extend the definition in the broader context of a cosmos meaning that different spacetimes can occur in the same cosmos making up a multiverse instead of a universe. In such a multiverse different types of energy can occupy the same space in superposition but phased out in time. Thus a space-like dimension can coexist in parallel with a time-like dimension occupying the same Cartesian space. I believe this space-like spacetime is occupied by dark energy, superluminous type of energy, opposite to normal luminous energy and matter in our light-like spacetime.

Comment: Personal theories shouldn't be disguised as answers in any stack exchange site.

Comment: @D.Halsey Sorry but this is your personal assessment and opinion about my answer unless you ague that there is a consensus of the definition which there is not. IMO, my definition given is 100% compatible with the other main answers. Space can excibit two different behaviors first dictated by the speed of causality thus time-like inside a medium or light-like in free space but also space-like when the expansion of the universe is taken into consideration or observed in QE experiments. For all means and purposes these are two different spacetimes within the same Cartesian space.