# Causality in Quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, measurements, causality, foundations

If we consider a quantum preparation procedure on a system followed by a  projection measurement  as constituting two sequential events in space-time (which seems plausible ,given that the Copenhagen interpretation demands us to describe quantum processes in terms of observable changes in the classical apparatus. We could for instance make a particular led light to glow for a particular ket's realization in the measurement process . That could constitute an event in space time .) , are these two events causally connected for any particular measurement outcome?

Comment: There is a trivial answer which is probably not what you want: two timelike separated events are always causally connected (see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/217805/109928). Maybe you could reformulate the question so that what you have in mind is made clearer.

Comment: If a single quantum experiment is being performed in an inertial system ,does the preparation procedure causally precedes the measurement process in all inertial frames?

Comment: If yes , it seems to me to be a feature which is additionally incorporated , rather than arising from quantum theory itself.Is that right?